# How to create AWS code pipleline for EBS to deploy on ASP.NET Core 5.0 with Angular

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have an ASP.NET Core 5.0 application with Angular. I want to deploy this application to the EBS Windows environment using AWS CodePipeLine (CI / CD). I have tried to get a lot of help from internet resources but have not found much.

Tried to create a pipeline but the deployment fails.

This is my `buildspec.yml` file:

```
# AWS CodeBuild spec to build an Elastic Beanstalk artifact for AWS CodePipeline to deploy
  version: 0.2
env:
   variables:
    PROJECT: AtlasWeb
    DOTNET_CORE_RUNTIME: 6.0

phases:   
   install:
    runtime-versions:
    dotnet: ${DOTNET_CORE_RUNTIME}
    nodejs: 16
commands :
  - npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
  - npm install -g @angular/cli@11.2.19
  - dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
  
pre_build:
 commands:
  - echo Restore started on `date`
  - dotnet restore AtlasWeb/AtlasWeb.csproj
  - npm install
  
build:
 commands:
  - echo Build started on `date`
  - dotnet build -c Release
  
  
post_build:
       commands:
       - echo Publish started on `date`
       - dotnet publish -c Release -o ./build_output AtlasWeb/AtlasWeb.csproj
```

I get this error at deployment phase:

> Deployment completed, but with errors: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version. Failed to deploy application. Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0e6eb9c4b3e517a18'. Aborting the operation. [Instance: i-0e6eb9c4b3e517a18 ConfigSet: Infra-WriteRuntimeConfig, Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild, Hook-PreAppDeploy, Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild, Hook-EnactAppDeploy, Hook-PostAppDeploy] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: null. Error occurred during build: Command hooks failed Deployment Failed: Unexpected Exception

Answer (score 0):

Once you build your application with the required command in your `buildspec.yml`, you would need to pass the output artifact of CodeBuild as Input to the ElasticBeanstalk action in CodePipeline. In order to do that your, `buildspec.yml` needs an artifacts section.

```
version: 0.2
...
<all your build commands>
...
artifacts: 
  files: 
    - '**/*'
```

Your Codepipeline will have a `Source (CodeCommit or any Third party source) -> CodeBuild -> Elastic beanstalk action`. You should already have an EB application and environment created.

Note : EB has a separate action in CodePipeline, there's no need for CodeDeploy stage. CodeDeploy only deploys to EC2/ECS via CodePipeline.

Coming to the error you are seeing, that's coming from the Elastic Beanstalk and not CodePipeline. You would need to check the `/var/log/eb-activity.log` in your instance or you can go to EB console -> logs -> Download -> Full Logs and extract the zip. `eb-activity.log` will have the command which was failing in the given instance and you need to troubleshoot accordingly.